# Xamarin IOS Build Error "Extracting Zip entry would have resulted in a file outside the specified destination directory."

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to build a new IOS release and get the following error:

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.After.targets(80,3): error : There was an error unzipping the file bin\iPhone\AppStore\AppBundle\MyApp.zip: Extracting Zip entry would have resulted in a file outside the specified destination directory."

The output line that generates this error is:-

```
"/usr/bin/zip -r /Users/fred/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp/ca830d1e9af62a1e18d114cf402fd82be9cb814135209657390ffb486f0d0ee4/bin/iPhone/AppStore/AppBundle/MyApp.zip ../MyApp.app"
```

It appears that rather than going back to the parent directory and then zipping the "MyApp.app" directory, the process is creating a zip file with ".." as the root directory with "MyApp.app" as a sub directory, which explains the above error.

I can deploy a debug build to a device, but I cannot build an AppStore release or do an Archive process.  My project previously built fine using Visual Studio 2019, but I had to upgrade to get a certificate fix that was only corrected in Visual Studio 2022.

Is there any known fixes for this issue?

I'm using:

- Visual Studio v17.3.1
- Xamarin v5.0.0.2515
- Windows 11 machine

Compiling against;

- macOS Monterey v12.5.1
- Xcode v13.4.1

Comment: Try to remove the `bin` directory (in the project) and all the files on Mac in ~/library/caches/mtbs/builds/ and then rebuild it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Comment out or delete this 'Unzip' task

```
<!--Unzip App Bundle on Windows-->
<Unzip Condition="Exists('$(DeviceSpecificOutputPath)AppBundle\$(_AppBundleName).zip')" ZipFilePath="$(DeviceSpecificOutputPath)AppBundle\$(_AppBundleName).zip" ExtractionPath="$(DeviceSpecificOutputPath)AppBundle\$(_AppBundleName)$(AppBundleExtension)" />
```

in the file

> ..\Community\Msbuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.After.targets

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Opened MS dev com "Xamarin iOS deployment no longer works".

I did find something that works for me. Select to Archive iOS build and wait for error. Select View Archive + failing iOS build, tap Distribute, cancel the creds challenge, tap Open Folder, and submit the ipa to Apple.